# Android 4.0 x86 full can install on all PC

Tags: android

I want a download link for Android 4 x86 full
install on pc 
- support all device 
- support numpad 
- support all resolution 
and any feature for working perfect and download size not important for me

Comment: I want to download android x86 os

Comment: Simply go to the Android SDK manager and download it. It's pretty straight forward.

Comment: @Warpzit I already have Android SDK!!! ,I want Android 4 OS for install in PC same as laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this links can help you :
http://www.android-x86.org/download  ( especially iso files )

https://thepiratebay.se/torrent/7517017/[offline]_Android_SDK_4.1_Full_4.1_x86_[2012__ENG]
this is not 4.0 but newer

Comment: I want to install in my pc